# What contributes to expanded company details being displayed in Google search results?

Tags: google-search, search-results

For some results returned in Google Search, on the right side it displays the company details, logo, contact numbers, etc...

For example, see the following screenshot:

[image]

I'd like to know what contributes to this so that I can try to achieve it for my site too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wikipedia's effect on Google SEO](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61824/wikipedias-effect-on-google-seo)

Answer (score 2):

From: http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2272084/How-to-Dominate-the-Entire-First-Page-of-Google

> Google+
>
> Brands that have verified Google+ accounts can capture side rail real
>   estate for brand terms by utilizing rel="publisher". This works
>   similarly to authorship but is tied to Google+ pages as opposed to
>   individual accounts. The result is a rather large piece of real estate
>   that includes your follower count and a link with image to your latest
>   post.
>
> For more information on how to set up your publisher profile, check
>   out this [Google+ starter guide](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2255270/Google-A-Quick-Start-Guide).

You will notice that this only occurs when a brand search is entered. If your brand consists of fairly common words, this may not work as well.

Comment: Is this answer still accurate? Google has recently scaled back integration between Google+ and Google Search.

Comment: @JustinSkiles Not sure. Google recently began to downplay their requirements for Google+. There are 46 branding signals (by my last count that I can remember). Part of this is trust that a brand really is a brand. Google+ sends a strong signal to Google that a company really is a company. Fair or not, Google+ played a major role in establishing trust for sites. This never really fully made sense to me in light of those sites that have theirs sites registered with Google Webmaster Tools and other apps that do the same thing.

Comment: @JustinSkiles For the record, Google did up the requirement for social engagement big-time. This means if not Google+, then LinkedIn, Twitter, Facebook, etc. As for me, this is just plain wrong. Social media is not appropriate for every site nor does it mean that a site has little to no value simply because of a lack of social media. Think of the Phd professor and his site as an example. Of all the professors and researchers I deal with who are experts and very active in their field as thought leaders, none of them are engaged in social media at all. Brands, however, are very involved in SM.

Answer (score 2):

Since in some cases the information is taken from Wikipedia, you might as well try and create a Wikipedia page for your brand.

Google+ pages help with location of physical addresses, comments, pictures and so on.

As you can see in the image you posted, Wikipedia info shows up first, then the location and other info from Google+

Comment: Nice point about Wikipedia!

Comment: First i will add google+ to my website and then i will go wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

It can get the info from various places - eg Wikipedia, imdb, Google+ business pages.  Usually external sources will be credited, so you can see if you can copy.

If your business is local, then it is certainly worth using Google with Places for Business so it appears on the map.

https://www.google.co.uk/business/

That appears to be what the one in your example are doing.

It won't always appear on the right hand side, but means your company may still appear on map searches, and also may help if people are doing local searches.

PS DON'T spam Wikipedia.  If you are big enough, someone else will create an unbiased page for you.  If you are a small company, you will be taken down by the moderators as not relevant.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Starting_an_article#Things_to_avoid