# Does the Wikipedia summary next to the URL of a search result come from the Knowledge Graph?

Tags: google-search, search-results, knowledge-graph

Similar to this question here: (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61824/wikipedias-effect-on-google-seo) but a bit different.

I recently noticed that on the main listing for some companies have a grey drop down option right next to their green URL. When you click it, the box usually displays a one sentence summary of a company taken from Wikipedia.

[image: Google SERP: Dropdown with information about Amazon from Wikipedia]

Is this dropdown generated by the Knowledge Graph or something else?

I've seen it on listings of companies with fully filled out Knowledge Graphs and on listings with nothing in the Knowledge Graph right bar.

Comment: Yes. This is knowledge graph stuff. You can see where it comes from in your image.

Comment: I saw that, but I also happened to see listings with this that didn't have the knowledge graph bar on the right. I guess there was something else happening there but it was still coming from the same source.

Comment: Yes. This is rather new. I am not sure what to call it exactly, but it is the same mechanism apparently.

Answer (score 1):

This information comes from the knowledge graph and not just from completed company profiles but also from data sourced from highly authoritative sources which have been used to add data to the knowledge graph.